# Itamaeで外部リポジトリを追加した後に apt-get update を走らせる方法

Tags: itamae, apt

`Itamae`で以下のように`apt`の外部リポジトリを追加した後に`apt-get update`をhookさせて走らせたいんですが、何か良い方法はありますか？

```
remote_file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mesosphere.list' do
  source 'files/mesosphere.list'
end
```

`Itamae`で外部リポジトリを追加する一般的な書き方を
探してはみたのですが見つかりませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscribe` を利用して以下のようにしてます。
[itamae実践Tips](http://qiita.com/sue445/items/b67b0e7209a7fae1a52a#%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8C%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84) こちらの記事の解説がとてもわかりやすいです。

```
remote_file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mesosphere.list' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
end

execute 'apt-get update' do
  subscribes :run, "remote_file[/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mesosphere.list]", :immediately
  action :nothing
end
```

Comment: `subscribes`というのがあるんですね。勉強になりました、ありがとうございます。